# How to send raw binary blob payload with POST request in React Native?

Tags: react-native, post, blob

Original Function:

```
fn: async () => {
    var start = Date.now()
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(tuneFile.length); //bytes is the array with the integer
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

    for (var i = 0; i < tuneFile.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = tuneFile[i];
    }

    var blob = new Blob([ia], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", blob, "tune1.bin")
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: form,
    };
    const response = await fetch('http://192.168.4.1/upload', requestOptions);
    const data = await response.text();
    console.log(data)
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log(end - start)
    return true
}
```

React Native version of same function:

```
fn: async () => {
    var start = Date.now()
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(tuneFile.length); //bytes is the array with the integer
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

    for (var i = 0; i < tuneFile.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = tuneFile[i];
    }

    var blob = new Blob([ia], {type: 'multipart/form-data'});
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", blob, "tune1.bin")
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': blob.type,
      }
    };

    axios.post('http://192.168.4.1/upload', form, config)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.request.status)
      return true;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    //var end = Date.now();
    //return true
}
```

Context:
The first function is written for a simple node app. The second one is for React Native.
React Native doesn't play well with blobs and i think that's where the issue lies.

The function takes a 'tuneFile' which is just a node buffer in hex. After doing some conversions into a Blob, it then sends it to another server with a POST request. The first func works as intended, sending the file in chunks. The second one sends a request and gets a 200 status, but the server never registers a payload.

How can i change the SECOND function to operate the same as the first?

Comment: Why are you doing `{ type: "application/octet-stream" }` in non-React Native but `{type: 'multipart/form-data'}` in React Native?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/network React Native uses fetch. Try to use fetch in React Native instead of Axios.

Comment: Hey brandon, I've tried a lot of stuff with the RN code, so this is just the latest thing i tried. I've already tried with octet-stream. RN uses fetch, but it has a limited version that doesn't work with blob types. There is a package called RN-Fetch-Blob that seems to be to GOTO library, but i couldn't get that library to work either.

Comment: At this point I would try stuff like hex encoding, base64 encoding, uploading chunks, etc. That's just me personally though. I try not to let perfect be the enemy of good, but I do know you are battling memory/CPU constraints all over the place.

Comment: I also would consider making the device "dumb" and just being able to handle basic UDS flash commands like 10/11/27/34/36/37/31, etc.

Then you are just sending it a chunk of data instead of having to upload the entire tune file.